# iterate through datatable in c#

Tags: c#

i have an datatable like this.
 i have  got the data  from sqlserver  and  stored in a  datatable in c#

```
 User       Svc     VSS
   kiran      6.5    8
   kiran      0.5    8
   manu       0.0   4.0
   manu       0.0   4.0
   Priya      9.0   0.7
   Priya      9.0   0.7
   Peter      4.5   1.5
   Peter     .0    .5
```

now i need  result like this in another datatable

```
   User       Svc     VSS
   kiran      7.0     16.0
   manu       0.0     8.0
   Priya      18.0    1.4
   Peter      4.5     6.5
```

how can  i achive this result set,

any help would be grealty apprecaited
 thanks
 prince

Comment: do you need the first dataset for something else? Any reason you're not using SELECT User, SUM(Svc) AS Svc, SUM(VSS) AS VSS FROM...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use TypeDataSet and the table name=tableName then by using linq you can do it easily as following..

```
        var query = from row in tableName.AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.User into Group                        
                    select new
                    {
                        User = Group.Key,
                        SvcSum = Group.Sum(r => r.svc),
                        VssSum = Group.Sum(r => r.vss)
                    };

        foreach (var grp in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", grp.User, grp.SvcSum, grp.VssSum);
        }
```

I have test it by creating table and project. i think this will be helpful for you.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would probably be to aggregate this in a stored procedure instead of trying to iterate through a datatable.

```
select
   [User],
   sum(SVC),
   sum(VSS)
from
   DataTable
group by
   [User]
```